# Why am I getting a a null object reference error?

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I am trying to show a custom minute interval in the time picker, so here is what I'm trying to do.
In my MainActivity I have this method(called on a button click),which is opening a d`DialogFragment`:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
```

Here is the `TimePickerFragment`:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DurationTimePickDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = 0;

        // Create a new instance of CustomTimePickerDialog and return it
        return new CustomTimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        String realMinute= "";

        switch (minute) {
            case 1:
                realMinute = "01";
                break;
            case 2:
                realMinute = "02";
                break;
            case 3:
                realMinute = "03";
                break;
            case 4:
                realMinute = "04";
                break;
            case 5:
                realMinute = "05";
                break;
            case 6:
                realMinute = "06";
                break;
            case 7:
                realMinute = "07";
                break;
            case 8:
                realMinute = "08";
                break;
            case 9:
                realMinute = "09";
                break;
            default:
                realMinute = String.valueOf(minute);
                break;
        }

        final String selectedDate = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + realMinute;
        EditText selectedTimeTxt = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.selectedTime);
        selectedTimeTxt.setText(selectedDate);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using a customized class called `CustomTimePickerDialog` in order to show the dialog with the 10 minute interval. Here the code is:

```
public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {

    private final static int TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL = 5;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private final OnTimeSetListener callback;

    public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener callBack,
                                  int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView) {
        super(context, callBack, hourOfDay, minute / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL,
                is24HourView);
        this.callback = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (callback != null && timePicker != null) {
            timePicker.clearFocus();
            callback.onTimeSet(timePicker, timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                    timePicker.getCurrentMinute() * TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        try {
            Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
            Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");
            this.timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField
                    .getInt(null));
            Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

            NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
            mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
            mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) - 1);
            List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL) {
                displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
            }
            mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues
                    .toArray(new String[0]));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is that I'm getting this strange for me error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.NumberPicker.setMinValue(int)' on a null object reference` regarding this line: `mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);` - in the `CustomTimePickerDialog` class.

I know that I'm messing the things here(probably in the `TimePickerFragment` class), but as an android and java beginner I'm not able to spot my mistake.

Can you give me a clue?

Comment: What if you invoke `NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) findViewById(field.getInt(timePicker));` instead? And perhaps `Field field = TimePicker.class.getField("minute")`.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Cannot resolve symbol 'timePicker'`

Comment: `this.timePicker` then.

Comment: @AndyTurner `this.timePicker` is returning null and the `field` change says `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: minute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                .findViewById(field.getInt(null));
```

is presumably returning `null`.

Comment: `this.timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField
                    .getInt(null));` returns a result.

Comment: @Slim - Always? (I'm assuming you mean 'non-null result')

Comment: yep, always. I don't know what is wrong with `mMinuteSpinner` :(

Comment: @Slim - in that case, you need to provide more information (like the full stack trace, for instance). The error message says that you are invoking a `setMinValue` on a `null` instance of `NumberPicker`. This is the only place that it looks like you're invoking that method in the code you have given.

Comment: Because this is the only place I'm invoking it. :) But I still can't understand why it returns null. :(

Comment: @Slim - how do you know that it isn't `null`? The evidence (an error message stating that the only place a method is invoked is on a `null` object) very strongly suggests that it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70476/discussion-between-andy-turner-and-slim).

Comment: I don't, but how should I know and WHY it's null? It is not supposed to be null in any way. :(

Answer (score 0):

android.widget.NumberPicker.setMinValue(int) on a null object reference
so it says its being called on null object that means mMinuteSpinner is null for sure the JVM doesn't go wrong dude just debug your code If you need help i'll help you debug

NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker
                    .findViewById(field.getInt(null));

```
        mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
```

Comment: :) I already tried to debug it and believe me, I see nothing... :(

Comment: Does mMinuteSpinner have a not null value ?

Comment: yes so your object is null and basically your statement Field field = classForid.getField("minute"); is not correct try and get list of all available fields and then see if minute is there in  TimeDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
final View v = l.inflate(R.layout.create_alarm_dialog, null);

//get the number pickers
NumberPicker hoursNP = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.hours);
```

This is how I did mine, I'm guessing you need to specify the view so it knows where to look for the ID. Sorry I'm also a noob at android and this is my first stackover flow post. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
```

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.NumberPicker.setMinValue(int)' on a null object reference

> Blockquote

Still crash in android version 11 API level 30 like Oppo, Samsung, Realme, OnePlus, etc. mobile devices